# CSS Follow Mouse Effect

Tags: javascript, html, css

How to create a mouse follow effect like in the picture that has an arrow, the arrow is the line mouse follower object, while the red box is the width where the  effects takes place.

[image]

Comment: It is unclear what you want to achieve. Do you want a red arrow following your mouse? What have you attempted so far? Keep in mind Stack Overflow is not a code writing service, giving us a vague specification and expecting code in return is not likely to be well recieved.

Comment: show what you have attempted.

Comment: pls be more specific in your question :) Show us some code

Comment: Hey Sasori , as far as I understood , you need to create that within every individual menu items with position absolute and width 0 . Once you hover on item , this width should be 100% . This way you can achieve. Providing some code can help us and you in greater way.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the replies. @JonP Sorry this is my first time to ask a question here in stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are talking about this type of menu

```css
#cssmenu ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 1;
  display: block;
  zoom: 1;
}

#cssmenu ul:after {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  font-size: 0;
  height: 0;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
}

#cssmenu ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#cssmenu.align-right ul li {
  float: right;
}

#cssmenu.align-center ul {
  text-align: center;
}

#cssmenu ul li a {
  color: #434351;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  padding: 15px 25px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 14px;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: color .25s;
  -moz-transition: color .25s;
  -ms-transition: color .25s;
  -o-transition: color .25s;
  transition: color .25s;
}

#cssmenu ul li a:hover {
  color: #333333;
}

#cssmenu ul li a:hover:before {
  width: 100%;
}

#cssmenu ul li a:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 3px;
  width: 0;
  background: #434351;
  -webkit-transition: width .25s;
  -moz-transition: width .25s;
  -ms-transition: width .25s;
  -o-transition: width .25s;
  transition: width .25s;
}

#cssmenu ul li.last>a:after,
#cssmenu ul li:last-child>a:after {
  display: none;
}

#cssmenu ul li.active a {
  color: #434351;
}

#cssmenu ul li.active a:before {
  width: 100%;
}

#cssmenu.align-right li.last>a:after,
#cssmenu.align-right li:last-child>a:after {
  display: block;
}

#cssmenu.align-right li:first-child a:after {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  #cssmenu ul li {
    float: none;
    display: block;
  }
  #cssmenu ul li a {
    width: 100%;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fb998c;
  }
  #cssmenu ul li.last>a,
  #cssmenu ul li:last-child>a {
    border: 0;
  }
  #cssmenu ul li a:after {
    display: none;
  }
  #cssmenu ul li a:before {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id='cssmenu'>
  <ul>
    <li class='active'><a href='#'><span>Home</span></a></li>
    <li><a href='#'><span>Products</span></a></li>
    <li><a href='#'><span>Company</span></a></li>
    <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Contact</span></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: This isn't actually the answer I was looking for. but i guess this is awesome too. Thanks @Ezzuddin